# How to create pages in one note native client in windows wpf application OFFLINE?

Tags: wpf, onenote

How to talk with native one note client and create pages and sections in WPF application offline? As per my search there is no API exposed for One note native client to do this. Our requirement is to create pages offline and write something on it. When online this pages should sync with onedrive. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of exploration, I came to know that onenote store does't work Offline. It was developed to work in online only. If you want to create notebooks and modify them offline then use Onenote Desktop and Application Interface to talk with it.

Comment: Which version of OneNote are you referring to?

Comment: its onenote store app.

Comment: We can't create Onenotes offline in Store app. But Windows is providing Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote library to create Notebooks, sections, and update pages. Mote information about this offline interface is available here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx